# Передача параметров при вызове нативных функций с++ из андроида

Tags: java, c++, qt, android-ndk

В Qt Creator содан проект под андроид. Вот два файла с кодом:

c++

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include <QtAndroidExtras>

void pass_int(int value) {
    qDebug() << "pass_int: " << value;
}

void pass_double(double value1, double value2, double value3) {
    qDebug() << "pass_double: " << value1 << " : " << value2 << " : " << value3;
}

void test() {
    JNINativeMethod methods[] {
        {"pass_int", "(I)V", reinterpret_cast<void*>(&pass_int)},
        {"pass_double", "(DDD)V", reinterpret_cast<void*>(&pass_double)},
    };

    QAndroidJniObject java_class("ptz.andk.Jmain");
    QAndroidJniEnvironment env;
    jclass obj = env->GetObjectClass(java_class.object<jobject>());
    env->RegisterNatives(obj, methods, 2);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(obj);

    QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<void>(
        "ptz/andk/Jmain",
        "test",
        "()V",
        QtAndroid::androidActivity().object());
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
    &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    test();

    return app.exec();
}
```

и java

```
package com.andk;

public class Jmain {
    private static native void pass_int(int value);
    private static native void pass_double(double value1, double value2, double value3);

    public static void test() {
        pass_int(123);
        pass_double(1.23, 2.34, 3.45);
    }
}
```

В функции test регистрируются две нативные функции и вызывается java функция test, в которой просто вызывются зарегистрированные нативные функции.

Я ожидаю получить вывод:

```
pass_int:  123
pass_double:  1.23  :  2.34  :  3.45
```

Но при запуске на эмуляторе получается

```
pass_int:  44720832
pass_double:  1.23  :  2.34  :  3.45
```

а при запуске на реальном устройстве

```
pass_int:  -709912000
pass_double:  -8.06905e-10  :  1.23  :  2.34
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут неправильная сигнатура экспортируемых jni функций. Первые два параметра должны быть указателями на рантайм и объектом-классом. Кроме того, функции должны быть объявлены как noexcept во избежание пробрасывания c++ исключения через границу языка.

```
void pass_int
(
    ::JNIEnv * const p_env
,   ::jclass const Jmain_class
,   ::jint const value
) noexcept
```

Comment: Возьми андроид студию, в ней сделай проект для ндк для твоего класса, опиши нужные функции в своем классе, студия тебе сгенерирует правильные сигнатуры в сишном хидере. их скопируй себе в проект и пиши под них код.

Comment: Понял, спасибо всем.